# Numerical example of Coordinate ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am self-studying Algebraic geometry and was looking for a numerical exercise to concretise my intuition on how the coordinate ring works.
I came across the following exercise on google ([this lecture notes](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Edmehrle/notes/old/alggeo/34CoordinateRingonAffineVariety.pdf))

### Exercise 1

Consider the variety $V = \boldsymbol{V}(x^2 + y^2 - 1) \subseteq k^2$. List three distinct polynomials in $k[x, y]$ that are the same function when considered as elements in $k[V]$.

### My answer

By solving $x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$ w.r.t. $y$, we get $y = \pm \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ so we got two.
And the constant function $y = 0$ satisfies the condition.

Am I right?

Comment: Pick any $f\in k[x,y]$, consider its image $[f]$ in the quotient $k[x,y]/\mathbf{I}(V)$, and find two more distinct representatives of the equivalence class $[f]$. You can do this by just adding multiples of $x^2+y^2-1$ to $f$. So I'm thinking something like: $f=0$, $g=x^2+y^2-1$, and $h=xg=x^3+xy^2-x$. Then $f,g,h$ are distinct polynomials, but they all give the zero-map when considered as functions $V\to k$.

Comment: The problem can be rephrased as "Find $3$ polynomials which agree on $V \subset k^2$ but not necessarily on the other points of $k^2$." As such you're answer is not quite right, since the expressions $y \pm \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ are not polynomials.

Comment: @morrowmh oh, it's a smart way and that makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since building intuition is something that usually comes with experience, this is a difficult question to answer, but I'll try my best with a few examples.

Firstly, I suggest thinking of an algebraic variety as a geometric object. So, when I say the variety define by the polynomial $x^2 + y^2 -1$, it is the circle in $k^2$ of radius $1$ with center are the origin (when you get more comfortable with these, you will think of it as a closed subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ - but if you are not comfortable with this right now, I suggest you ignore this comment I made). Similarly, an algebraic variety defined by the equations $x$ and $y$ is a straight line in $k^3$, i.e. the $z$-axis. And, the variety defined by $x^2+y^2+1$ is also some geometric figure in $k^2$ which doesn't have any name (or at least, I haven't heard one) because over $\mathbb{R}$, this is empty.

Now that we have our three examples, lets try to understand the coordinate ring for each of these examples. To explain, the coordinate ring is made up of the polynomial functions on these spaces. The important word to note here is 'functions'. You are no longer looking at the polynomial ring as an abstract ring, but a ring of functions on the variety. Because some non-zero polynomials turn out to be the zero-function on these varieties, different polynomials can define the same function.

$\textbf{Exmple 1:}$ $x^2+y^2-1$

From the definition of the coordinate ring, I hope it is clear that there is a surjection $k[x,y]\rightarrow k[V]$. But, the function defined by $x^2+y^2 -1$ is zero on every point of this variety (i.e., for every $(\alpha,\beta)\in V$, we have that $\alpha^2+\beta^2-1=0$). So, the kernel of this contains the ideal defined by $x^2+y^2-1$. It is not hard to verify that this ideal is exactly the kernel. So, $k[V]=k[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$. Now, any two functions $f,g\in k[x,y]$ define the same function on $V$, if they have the same image in $k[V]$, i.e. $f-g\in (x^2+y^2-1)$. So, to solve your exercise, you just need to pick three polynomials $f_1,f_2, f_3\in k[x,y]$ such that $(f_1-f_2),(f_2-f_3),(f_3-f_1)\in (x^2+y^2-1)$.

$\textbf{Example 2:}$  $x,y$
In this case, we have a surjection $k[x,y,z]\rightarrow k[V]$. The polynomial $x$ and the polynomial $y$ are identically zero as functions on this space. Therefore, the polynomials in the ideal $(x,y)$ are all identically zero as functions on this space. Just as before, we can show that this is exactly the kernel and hence $k[V]= k[x,y,z]/(x,y)$

$\textbf{Example 3:}$ $y^2+x^2+1$

Lastly, this example is also just like the last two and the coordinate ring is $k[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1)$. This highlights an important fact that even if the set of solutions is empty, the coordinate ring is not necessarily zero. This is because you can change the base of algebraic varieties, i.e. you can define them over larger fields where solutions might exist - and base change results in and extension of scalars (using tensor product) of the coordinate ring. This is one reason why I had mentioned earlier that you should think of the variety define in your question as a subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ rather than a subset of $k^2$. These ideas can be made more precise using schemes (which if you continue to study algebraic geometry will become your bread and butter). Honestly, if this last discussion seems confusing, at this stage, it is completely harmless to ignore it.